Why is my odoo xml record data not updating
I inherited a module (Recruitment module) and then tried updating the xml data but all my attempt is not working.
I tried updating group like hr_recruitment.group_hr_recruitment_user but the update is not working still.
See my codes:
xml ->
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="0">
    
        <record id="hr_recruitment.stage_job1" model="hr.recruitment.stage">
            <field name="active">0</field>
        </record>
        <record id="hr_recruitment.stage_job2" model="hr.recruitment.stage">
            <field name="active">0</field>
        </record>
        <record id="hr_recruitment.stage_job3" model="hr.recruitment.stage">
            <field name="active">0</field>
        </record>
        <record id="hr_recruitment.stage_job4" model="hr.recruitment.stage">
            <field name="active">0</field>
        </record>
        <record id="hr_recruitment.stage_job5" model="hr.recruitment.stage">
            <field name="active">0</field>
        </record>
    
    </data>
    
</odoo>

python ->
from odoo import models, fields, api, _

class hrRecruitmentStageInherit(models.Model):
_inherit = "hr.recruitment.stage"
group_ids = fields.Many2many('res.groups')
stage_type = fields.Selection(
    selection=[
        ('initiation', 'Initiation'),
        ('interview', 'Interview'),
        ('selection_process', 'Selection Process'),
        ('documentation', 'Documentation'),
        ('audit', 'Audit'),
        ('accounts_finance', 'Accounts / finance'),
        ('background_checks', 'Background Checks')
    ],
    string='Stage Type'
)

active = fields.Boolean(default=True)

manifest ->
{
'name': "HR CBT Recruitment ",

'sequence': 10,

'depends': [
    'base',
    'hr_recruitment',
    'hr_recruitment_survey',
    'website_hr_recruitment',
     'hr_recruitment_sign',
],

'data': [
    'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    'security/security_view.xml',
    'views/hr_recruitment_stage_inherit.xml',
    'data/hr_recruitment_data.xml',  # Where the records are

],

}
I was expecting the records to be archived

What have you tried? Can’t see your code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

As you can see the records I tried updating the existing records but my update is not working. I have provided more codes to give you the context.

@Robert This question is closed because the debugging data is missing but unfortunately, you can't get the debugging details. Everything you need is in the question. Closing this question because of debug data is wrong

In update mode, the record won't be updated if the data node explicitly opt-out using @noupdate="1". Those records are marked Non Updatable
You need to set noupdate to False and update records (then reset the noupdate to True)
Example:
<function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
    <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
        <value eval="[('name', '=like', 'stage_job_'), ('model', '=', 'hr.recruitment.stage')]"/>
    </function>
    <value eval="{'noupdate': False}"/>
</function>

<record id="hr_recruitment.stage_job1" model="hr.recruitment.stage">
    <field name="active">0</field>
</record>
<record id="hr_recruitment.stage_job2" model="hr.recruitment.stage">
    <field name="active">0</field>
</record>
<record id="hr_recruitment.stage_job3" model="hr.recruitment.stage">
    <field name="active">0</field>
</record>
<record id="hr_recruitment.stage_job4" model="hr.recruitment.stage">
    <field name="active">0</field>
</record>
<record id="hr_recruitment.stage_job5" model="hr.recruitment.stage">
    <field name="active">0</field>
</record>

<function name="write" model="ir.model.data">
    <function name="search" model="ir.model.data">
        <value eval="[('name', '=like', 'stage_job_'), ('model', '=', 'hr.recruitment.stage')]"/>
    </function>
    <value eval="{'noupdate': True}"/>
</function>


Wow! That is really great! I will check it out.

I have tested it before posting this answer!

Sorry, it really worked. But it required me to set noupdate="0" since I am upgrading the module and not installing. Thanks for that.
